# Return value from second key if value from first key exists

Tags: php, arrays

I have the output of a PHP to a server API and need to pull all the mac address values from the `dst_mac` keys, but only on the occasion the category `catname` keys value for each element is `emerging-p2p`

The format of the array is like this (intermediate keys and values removed for brevity)

```
    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [_id] => 5c8ed5b2b2302604a9b9c78a
        [dst_mac] => 78:8a:20:47:60:1d
        [srcipGeo] => 
        [dstipGeo] => stdClass Object
            (
            )

        [usgipGeo] => stdClass Object
            (
            )
        [catname] => emerging-p2p
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example that is an array with a std class. you can use the empty funtion.

```
//checks if the first key
if (!empty($array[1]->_id)) {
  echo $array[1]->dst_mac;
  // or do what you want.
}
```

This example only applies to one array. use a loop to have this dynamically done.

EDIT: My answer was based on your question. Didn't realize you have to check the catname to be 'emerging-p2p' before you get the mac address?

```
// loop through the array
foreach ($array as $item) {
  // checks for the catname
  if ($item->catname === 'emerging-p2p') {
    // do what you want if the cat name is correct
    echo $item->dst_mac;
  }
}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: While thats does work, it only returns the first occurrence

Comment: The loop version works exactly as expected and needed! Very much appreciate this, it was driving me nuts!

Comment: @AdrianM at what part are you having problems with?

Comment: Sorry, in case i wasnt clear with my previous comment, the loop version works just fine, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i =0;$i<count($arr);$i++){ 
   if(isset($arr[$i]['catname']) && $arr[$i]['catname']=='emerging-p2p'){
        echo $arr[$i]['dst_mac'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Illegal string offset 'catname'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) if you need only `mac address` on the basis of `catname`.

```
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($arr),true); // to cast it as array
$temp = array_column($arr, 'dst_mac', 'catname');
echo $temp['emerging-p2p'];
```

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56e435fe21c439ea2c164108c3b6c99fe767a18e).

Comment: While thats does work, it only returns the first occurrence.

Comment: @AdrianM Can you please elaborate a little? Try using `print_r($temp)` below definition of `$temp` variable

Comment: Added printr($temp['emerging-p2p']);  but it only returns 2 of the 19 instances from my test array...

Comment: In such a scenario, you must update your input array with all the scenarios which you think needs to be covered.  By just seeing one element of array, you won't get a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one object that has 'emerging-p2p' cat name:

```
foreach ($your_list_of_objects as $obj) {
    if ($obj->catname == 'emerging-p2p') {
        return $obj->dst_mac;
    }
}
```

If there are many:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($your_list_of_objects as $obj) {
    if ($obj->catname == 'emerging-p2p') {
        $result[]= $obj->dst_mac;
    }
}
return $result;
```

Comment: Sorry, but errors out: FastCGI-stderr: PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$dst_mac

Comment: @AdrianM so there are objects without dst_mac property, if it's ok, replace `$result[]= $obj->dst_mac;` to 
`if (isset($obj->dst_mac)) {
        $result[]= $obj->dst_mac;`
    }
`

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop.

```
for($i =0; $i<=count($arr); $i++){ 
   if(arr[$i]['catname']=='emerging-p2p'){
        echo arr[$i]['dst_mac'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but errors out:  Illegal string offset 'catname'

Comment: Problem might be is that your variable $array is not set or initialized as an array(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fetch all the mac where catname is `emerging-p2p`

```
//Assuming $arr has array of objects
$result_array = array_filter($arr, function($obj){
    if ($obj->catname == 'emerging-p2p') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

foreach ($result_array as $value) {
    echo $value->dst_mac;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly as well. Very much aprpeciated!